# Помогите отредактировать код с кортежем в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuple

[image: кортеж скриншот]Задание:

Предположим, у нас есть строка с некоторым алфавитом, и мы хотим сохранить все буквы из нее в кортеж. Прочтите входную строку и распечатайте этот кортеж.

Ожидаемый вывод:

('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z')

Мой код, который не работает (((((:

```
# work with this string
alphabet = tuple('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
print(alphabet)
```

Comment: А что у вас выводит? У меня выводит именно тот вывод, который ожидался.

Comment: Я выполняю задание на JetBrains (т.е. там такое розовое диалоговое окно, а не нормальный Python) и он мне написал, что
 "Неудачный тест № 2 из 5. Неверный ответ." 

Comment: Так может по заданию строку нужно откуда-то прочесть, а не задать в коде? Ну там через `input()`, например?

Comment: @CrazyElf сейчас попробую скрин задания прикрепить. Может быть вы посмотрите свежим взглядом и поможете мне)))

Comment: Обычно на таких сайтах есть некий шаблон чтения и записи данных и нужно его соблюдать. Обычно он в самых первых заданиях даётся, со стороны сложно может быть понять, что они хотят. Но я посмотрю.

Comment: Забавно, что в вопросе пример вывода не соответствует примеру ввода.

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, это забавно, очень странно так писать задания

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем задание: "прочтите эту строку". А код никакую строку не читает. Первый тест проходит, потому что там точно такая же строка на входе (т.е. на выходе), как в примере. А в других тестах другие строки!